# Delist entries in the_loop

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, loop, get-posts, meta-query

I am trying to add a delisting feature to my WordPress network. Posts which are delisted would not appear in post lists, but would still be visible if accessed directly.

I've written a plugin that helps editors delist entries with custom meta values on authors and posts. So there are two meta values that I need to check before displaying each post in public listings: the `delist-post` **post** meta value and the `delist-author` **user** meta value.

I was hoping to register a `pre_get_posts` filter that limits the return of `get_posts()` by setting the query's `meta_query` property. Is it possible to check a user meta value with a posts `meta_query`? If not, can you think of a better way to do this without adding conditional statements in theme files (i.e. not `if (!get_post_meta(...) && !get_user_meta(...))` in [the_loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after writing my question, The Theme Foundry wrote [a blog entry](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/query-posts-wordpress-false-null-meta-value/) that answered my question. The solution is to `add_action`s for both `posts_join` and `posts_where`. These each take clauses as arguments, which you append with your own conditions and return the appended clause.

In my case, I just had to limit the `join` in the `posts_join` callback:

```
$join .= " 
            LEFT JOIN    " . $wpdb->postmeta . " AS pm 
            ON           (" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID = pm.post_id AND 
                        pm.meta_key = 'post_meta_key_here') 
            LEFT JOIN    " . $wpdb->usermeta . " AS um 
            ON           (" . $wpdb->posts . ".post_author = um.user_id AND 
                        um.meta_key = 'author_meta_key_here') "
```

... and the `where` clause in the `posts_where` callback...

```
$where .= " 
                AND ((pm.meta_key = 'post_meta_key_here' AND pm.meta_value = 0)
                    OR pm.meta_id IS NULL) 
                AND ((um.meta_key = 'author_meta_key_here' AND um.meta_value = 0)
                    OR um.umeta_id IS NULL) ";
```

Please see [the blog post](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/query-posts-wordpress-false-null-meta-value/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `WP_Query` to do your loop it should be as simple as getting all the post IDs and then setting them as negative in the `p` parameter.

For example:

```
$unwanted_posts = array(); // you must generate this
$unwanted_posts_str = '-'.implode( ',-', $unwanted_posts );

$args = array(
    'p' => $unwanted_posts_str
);
```

You can also set this on an existing query using the `set()` method.

Comment: The list could be thousands of IDs long. (Edited to remove first sentence ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pre_get_posts`:

```
<?php
function wpse52961_filter_delisted_posts( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query
    // NOTE: You'll need to change this if
    // you intend to target a specific secondary query
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Define meta query
        $filtered_posts_meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'delist-post',
                'meta_value' => true
            ),
            array(
                'meta_key' => 'delist-author',
                'meta_value' => true
            )

        );
        // Add the meta query args to the query
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $filtered_posts_meta_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse52961_filter_delisted_posts' );
?>
```

I've made some assumptions about the meta key values, and the desired relationship between `delist-post` and `delist-author`.

Comment: The meta entries must exist or the post will be omitted. In a future version of WordPress, we will have an "exists/does not exist" criteria (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18158).

Also, delist-author must be attached to the user meta table, not posts meta, otherwise other posts by that author won't be delisted.